# Pulling Data from CSV vs. pulling data from database

Tags: taxonomy, options, csv

I developed a custom post type with a custom taxonomy for my WP theme and I need to add a number to associate with my taxonomy.

Example: The taxonomy is "store" and the average savings for that store is "20".

I created an interface to add average savings while creating and editing the taxonomy. The number is stored in wp_options table for the particular taxonomy ID.
On the other hand, my colleague created added a CSV file in the root directory and wrote a function to open the file and fetch the number according to the taxonomy name, every time a taxonomy page is loaded.

I just need to know which is the best method to do this and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading, searching and closing a file every time the page is loaded is highly time consuming. Database systems are highly optimized for reading and writing huge amount of records, querying data, providing schemes, relations between the data etc.

What will happen if 10K users hit the taxonomy page? How you will handle the updates of a taxonomy or the insertion of a new one in the file? How you can do efficiently queries regarding the value saved in the CSV file? What will happen if you delete the taxonomy or if the file has 1 million records?

**The proper way is to save it in a database.**

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120895/database-vs-file-system-storage) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356851/database-vs-flat-files)